# How can i get a program to loop through a changing list whilst performing operations

Tags: list, python-3.x, loops, element

Suppose I have two lists with elements that are natural numbers.

**Set A** *has n elements* and **Set B** *starts with a single element*.

---

Now could i code a program that takes a member from Set A, performs an operation
involving all the elements from Set B and then adds the element from set A to set B. Repeating this process until all elements from set A have been added to set B.

---

**Example:**

```
Set A = {3, 4, 5, 6} & Set B = {2}
```

Check to see if the first element from set A can be divided wholly by any element from set B. After this check has been done the first element from A goes to set B.

```
Set A = {4, 5, 6} & Set B = {2, 3}

Repeat

Set A = {5, 6} & Set B = { 2, 3, 4 } 

Repeat 

Set A = {6} & Set B = { 2, 3, 4, 5 }

Repeat

Set A = {} & Set B = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }

END
```

RESOLVED

```
def getprime(n):

for p in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(p)
```

Comment: use a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code solves your example question

> Check to see if the first element from set A can be divided wholly by all elements from set B. After this check has been done the first element from A goes to set B.

I hope you can understand how to apply this to other similar questions.

```
A = [2, 4, 5, 6]
B = [2]

# while the list A is not empty
while len(A) > 0:
    # the first number in the list
    num = A[0]
    # for every element in list B
    for j in B:
        fully_divisible = True
        # the the number is not divisible by a number from list B
        if num % j != 0:
            fully_divisible = False

    if fully_divisible:
        # this will only print if ALL the numbers currently in list B are divisible by num
        print num, "can be divided wholly by all elements from set B"
    else:
        # this will print if there is at least one number in list B the is not divisible by num
        print num, "cannot be divided wholly by all elements from set B"

    # remove the first element from list A, next time we loop the first element of the list (A[0]) will be different
    A.remove(num)
    # add that number to list B
    B.append(num)
```

Output:

```
2 can be divided wholly by all elements from set B
4 can be divided wholly by all elements from set B
5 cannot be divided wholly by all elements from set B
6 cannot be divided wholly by all elements from set B
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this it helps me immensely to see how one would go about it. Unfortunately it does not check against every element in B for example in your output 6 can be divided by 2.

Comment: @Dead_Ling0 It does check against every element in set B, but it only prints true the number `for instance 6` is divisible by ALL the numbers in set B (that is even written in the comments). The for loop `for j in B:` is the line that makes it so this code loops through every element in set B.

Comment: Sorry perhaps i should have been more clear ( i have now changed the all part from the question ) . What i meant to say is if there is at least 1 element in set B that can divide num wholly.  Rather than checking if num can be divided wholly by all the elements.

Comment: Try to see if you can solve it yourself, if you can't I will help you, but you should try it yourself because it is a aimple change.

Comment: I'm an idiot terrible at coding found what i was looking for and it was 6 simple lines i really should learn loops

Comment: You MUST learn loops, they are simple, easy to learn and extremely useful.